mysqlworkbench window will not resize, fresh install on Ubuntu 24.04
Very strange window behaviour.  Brand new install of latest 24.04 LTS.  Defaults for everything.  GNOME desktop (Wayland? I'm never sure.  Like I said, default.)  Mysqlworkbench installed via snap install mysql-workbench-community, Version 8.0.36.
When I open mysqlworkbench the window opens fine, filling maybe a third of my desktop.  I can use mouse-drag to move the window.  But I cannot mouse-click-drag to alter the window size at all.  Moving the mouse over the edges or corners does not cause the mouse cursor to change to "drag handles".  All other applications work fine.  It used to work fine for me under 22.04.  A friend who has 24.04 says it does work normally for him.  I can right-click in wb's "task bar at top", pick the "Resize" menu option: then it makes the mouse cursor be drag handles at top left and I can resize.  As soon as finished resizing reverts to "mouse cannot drag to resize".  As I say, every application other than mysqlworkbench works fine.
I have Googled and not found any matches.  Any ideas?!

To answer my own question after further investigation.
I uninstalled mysql-workbench-community and reinstalled, no difference.
On a whim I tried logging out of desktop and logging in again.  Lo and behold the mysqlworkbench window now correctly shows drag-handles and can be resized.  I have to do this every time after reboot.  This may somehow be related to the fact that my Ubuntu is set up to log me in directly to the desktop without going via the logon screen/entering password, which logging out and then logging back in does force me to do, I don't know.  I do know this was not necessary in previous versions of Ubuntu/GNOME desktop.
I leave this here in case anyone else experiences the same issue.
